# Trigger Airflow in postman

Tags: postman, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to trigger airflow dags in postman.
recently I am hitting
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/a_pipline/dagRuns/run_id

It's asking for run_id.
How can I specify run id in dags

Answer (score 1):

I have found answers after a lot of struggle. Its working on postman restAPI
POST: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/a_pipline/dagRuns

body: select json formate
{

```
        "dag_run_id": "manual__2022-10-22T11:05:59.461142+00:00"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming to Airflow from 15 years of using LSF, the terminology trips me up.

A dag_id is its "name"

The above is a "dag_run_id", which is the id of an *instance* of a dag having run, or in the process of running. What LSF would call it's flow_id.

In LSF these are purely numerical, issued sequentially across all flow instances, 1,2,3 and so on.

In Airflow, these are datetimestamps, which theoretically are not unique across the whole system, but should be within a dag.

In the airflow CLI - you trigger a dag as follows:

airflow dags trigger name_of_the_dag

(glossing over authentication)

I'm just getting to grips with scripts doing this via the REST API...

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, even if it is an interesting comparison.